# "Please enter passphrase..." after disk restore using clonezilla

Tags: boot, encryption, clonezilla, cryptswap

Am using Ubuntu 16.04.
I cloned my disk using Clonezilla.
I ran the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.
I was unable to boot the system after the upgrade
I restored the cloned disk using Clonezilla.
Now, when I boot the machine, I get the message "Please enter passphrase for disk blahblah (cryptswap1) on none!" This message never appeared before the attempted upgrade.
I can type anything, or even just press Enter, and the boot process continues.
There is no apparent problem with the operation of the system. All my files seem to be available (although I do not know how to determine if there is a problem with the encrypted swap partition and I do not know how such a problem might be manifested).

```
/etc/fstab contains:
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=ecae7ec1-5c4e-4fb4-b08b-7a72ce8ea7da /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=857C-0A12  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
#UUID=5155273c-1e77-4d6a-802e-531823055a21 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/81af97a3-5ccf-4640-bc59-bdf52814c029 /media/robert/backup auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=backup 0 0
```

So, I have the following questions:

1. Why is this message appearing at boot time?
2. How can I determine if the message is indicative of some underlying problem?
3. How can I fix the problem (if it exists) and, in any case, avoid
   having that message appear?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 ... ` ? You can do that by putting a `#` in front of the line. If the message disappears then you can create a swapfile. But more on that later.

Comment: Commenting out `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1...` does not appear to change anything. The message still appears when booting.